# Code is not working for Scroll as i want it

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm using jquery to get an Event Scroll which will put some value to my div when window is scrolling
here is the code tell me if it's wrong and how can i make it run

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
   var scrPos = $(this).scrollTop();
   $('feedback').html('your Scroll Position is' + scrPos);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `$('feedback')` class or id

Comment: Could you mark an answer for your question, please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing the `.` or `#` in the selector if the feedback is `ID` then use `#` or if its class then use `.` to make the selector working in your code.

```
$('feedback').html('your Scroll Position is' + scrPos);
```

Comment: Now i really need a suggestion what should i use i want to do some animation work on Scrolling tell me should i use JQuery or CSS? i can't decide which to chose

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id of the feedback element is "feedback", you're missing the # in the identifier, so, it can't find the element to write the HTML to. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
   var scrPos = $(this).scrollTop();
   $('#feedback').html('your Scroll Position is' + scrPos);
});
```

If the element has a class called "feedback", then use a '.' instead of a '#', i.e. $('.feedback')